# How to extract single text from <a> tag using Beautiful soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So there are 3 text inside a tag, But I need to extract only single tag
below is my code of what I have written as

```py
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    source= requests.get('eg.com')
    soup =BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    article= soup.find('div',class_='content')
    b = article.li.a.text
```

which is returning all text inside  tag ,OUTPUT:

```
Apple
2 iteams
```

but I need only first text i.e Apple
HTML CODE AS FOLLOWS

```
<li class ="iteam">
   <a href="eg.com">
      " Apple "
       <span class ="count">
          ::before
          "2"
          <span class ="countlabel">items</span>
          ::after
       </span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Where's the code you're using to extract the text from the tag?

Comment: here is the code :

    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

     source= requests.get('eg.com')
    soup =BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
    article= soup.find('div',class_='content')
    b = article.li.a.text

Comment: Put the code in your *question* not the *comment* and do not delete the `HTML`.

Comment: i have just re edited the formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.contents[0]` to get first content inside the `<a>` tag (in this case the text `" Apple "`):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_doc = """
<li class ="iteam">
<a href="eg.com">
" Apple "
<span class ="count">
::before
"2"
<span class ="countlabel">
items</span>
::after
</span>
</a>
</li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

txt = soup.find(class_="iteam").a.contents[0].strip()
print(txt)
```

Prints:

```
" Apple "
```